# What template files do I need to customise custom-category-term-links rather than fall back on archive.php?

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-taxonomy, theme-development

in my theme (built from scratch), i addad custom post types and custom taxonomies. To my template structure i added:

- page-customname.php
- archive-customname.php
- category-customname.php
- tag-customname.php

I linked the taxonomy terms:

```
/*Custom Term Function*/
function custom_get_terms( $postID, $term ){

$terms_list = wp_get_post_terms($postID, $term);
$output = '';

$i = 0;
foreach( $terms_list as $term ){ $i++;
    if( $i > 1 ){ $output .= ' — '; }
    $output .= '<a href="' . get_term_link( $term ) . '">'. $term->name .'</a>';
}
return $output;
}

/*call in specific templates*/
<?php echo custom_get_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-cat' ); ?>
<?php echo custom_get_terms( $post->ID, 'custom-tag' ); ?>
```

In my inspector i see links like:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8888/wordpress/custom-cat/term-cat/">term-cat</a>
```

But when i click the link, i am presented with the archive.php.
How can that be, shouldn't the request fall back on category-customname.php? At least the documentation says that. Does anyone have an idea why this happens? Thank you. theo

Comment: have a look at the [template hierarchy](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#custom-taxonomies) for how you should name custom taxonomy templates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Custom taxonomies have templates named taxonomy-something in this hierarchy:

```
taxonomy-{taxonomy}-{term}.php
taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php
taxonomy.php
archive.php
index.php
```

So, yes, if you have no `taxonomy-custom-cat-term-cat.php`, `taxonomy-custom-cat.php` or `taxonomy.php` then `archive.php` will be used.

`category-something.php` will only be used for the built-in categories, if you are on a page showing posts from a category called "something."

Comment: You're welcome.  If the answer works for you then please consider accepting it & upvoting it.  This not only boosts my ego but helps keep the site tidy by showing questions as resolved.  Thanks.

Comment: I will, but i stumbled over another issue. I just converted the name of my existing category-customname.php into taxonomy-customname.php and still i get the archive.php. Do i have to alter the taxonomy.php in the core?

Comment: Never edit core, no. What are the real names of your taxonomy and file name?

Comment: my custom category: «category-comic»; and as i said i changed the existing «category-comics.php» into «taxonomy-category-comics.php»

Comment: Well your taxonomy name has no 's' on the end but your template names do: They don't match.  Also one oddity with WP (in my mind) is that the template hierarchy doesn't use the taxonomy-{taxonomy}.php when you try to access the URL mysite/category-comic/ but only when you try to go to mysite/category-comic/some-term/

Comment: thanks a lot for pointing out the misspelling. The link operates. Unfortunately my rep is low. But i appreciate your help.

Comment: Cool - glad it works! I upvoted the question too.